# Dx scratch org - Is it possible to automate setting up the controlling picklist for a field in a managed package

Tags: salesforcedx

We have cpq package installed in our scratch orgs. And inside cpq package, we have a field in quote called status which is a picklist field. We have also created a custom controlling picklist field called stage.

So every time when we create our scratch orgs, we need to manually set up this field and create the field dependency, otherwise since the controlled field is in managed package it will throw an error message (actually, a lot of error messages). Is there any approach to automate this？Last approach is to use selenium but hopefully we don't need to go that far